# Evaluate integral of zeroth order Bessel function of the first kind

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

What is the result of the integral below?

$$\int^{aZ}_0e^{-aZ}J_0(2i\sqrt{b\tau aZ})d(aZ)$$

With $J_0$ the zeroth order Bessel function of the first kind.

Comment: Confusion of variables.  I guess you want the indefinite integral of $e^{-x}J_0(2i\sqrt{kx})\,dx$.  I do not expect a closed form for this.

Comment: What would be the difference? This integral originates from the book Chemical Process Principles, equation 61 on page 1084.

Comment: Why do you think that they write 
   *"For this latter problem Schumann presented the solution in charts..."*

Comment: Aha, so manual calculation is the only option here.  Thanks for the responses!